# Could not find generator devise_token_auth:install

Tags: devise

rails g devise_token_auth:install
Could not find generator devise_token_auth:install.

Using rails 4
Ruby 2.1

Gemfile

gem 'bower-rails'

gem 'angular-rails-templates'

gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'

gem 'devise_token_auth', '~> 0.1.29'

group :development do

gem 'better_errors'

gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_21]

gem 'quiet_assets'

gem 'rails_layout'

end

How to get rid of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please do `bundle install` & also check your Gemfile.lock if devise_token_auth updated or not .

if not please check devise_token_auth version compatibility with your devise & rails version.

Hope this will work

```
rails g devise_token_auth:install [USER_CLASS] [MOUNT_PATH]
```

[USER_CLASS] => your model name. 
[MOUNT_PATH] => your routes path like /auth or /users